# Changing colour of tab control in Win32 application (MetaTrader 4)

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm looking for a way to change the background colour of the chart tabs in MT4 - see image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAIR6.png

There is no built in way to do this, however I was theorising it would be possible to walk through the object tree in some way using Win32 functions, find the correct control, and then set the background colour.

First - is this feasible or possible, to avoid me wasting time pursuing it? I understand that the application itself may constantly override the colour, even if I set it.

Second - can anyone please point me in the direction of an example of how this could be done?

I presume the basic idea is to walk through the ancestors of each chart window, and for each ancestor, iterate the children, until you find one that matches the correct type (tab) with the correct text label, and then modify the relevant property.

Unfortunately, I've got no Win32 experience to speak of, and I don't know where to begin. Google isn't turning up much that can help.

I can load C# dlls into MT4, if it's easier this way - perhaps there is some LINQ provider that will help?

Please excuse the somewhat vague nature of the question, but I thought someone on here would be able to point me the right way.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you used a tool like spy++/winspector to verify that the tabs are actually stock Win32 Controls as opposed to custom elements drawn by the application? (which looks likely)

Comment: I did not know about those tools. I've just run winspector - here is the MT4 app tree. There appears to be 1 window per chart tab, but I can't drill any further into the hierarchy - does this indicate that it is most likely a custom drawn element, as you suggested? http://i.imgur.com/7K7QAYz.png

Comment: LINQ... no. LINQ stands for Language INtegrated Query. It's about getting information from collections of things. (Vast simplification).  I take it the options described [at Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/university/how-to-use-meta-trader-4/charts-and-settings.asp) don't fit the bill?

Comment: There is no built in setting for this unfortunately. Yes, I am aware of what LINQ is, I wondered if someone had made a provider that could iterate through winapi object hierarchies.